# How to send value of checkbox and file from form with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have form and I want to send values from it with ajax to php script, but it doesn't send value of chceckbox if is it checked and doesnt't send file with avatar. So form send only values from text inputs, but not from checkbox and file. Can you help me please what is wrong?
Form:

```
<form action='' id='form1' method='post' name='form1' ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' value=''>
<input type='text' name='age' id='age' value=''>
<input type='text' name='hobby' id='age' hobby=''>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkPHP" id="chkPHP" value="checked">
<input type='file' name='avatar' id='avatar' value='insert avatar' SIZE='30' accept=''>
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Script to send values from form:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {

        $('#waiting').show(0);
        $('#form1');
        $('#error').hide(0);

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'pksZpacuj.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                age: $('#age').val(),
                hobby: $('#hobby').val(),
                chkPHP: $('#chkPHP').val(),
                avatar: $('#avatar').val()
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('#waiting').hide(0);
                $('#error').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                    .html(data.msg).show(0);
                if (data.error === true)
                    $('#form1');
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#waiting').hide(0);
                $('#error').removeClass().addClass('error')
                    .text('There was an error.').show(0);
                $('#form1');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading files via AJAX is quite hard, and won't work in all browsers. I would strongly recommend against it.

If you really want to, you could follow this great post: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax call, it may be easier to just send `data: $('#form1').serialize()` instead of each value separately.

FYI the file you send will be in the `$_FILES` array, not the `$_POST` in your php script.

Comment: Thanks for post, it solved problem with checkbox. :) File is in $_FILES array and still doesn't work. But maybe solve this problem with file link from Chevi.